# Element of a cyclic group of even order has two square roots?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

The problem Im struggling with is "Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $d$. If $d$ is even, then each element of $G$ has either two or zero square roots in $G$"

Does this mean I need to find a cyclic group with an odd number of elements where each element $e$ can be expressed as $e^2$ .

Also, if $d$ is odd, then is it also true that if $d$ is odd then every element of $G$ has exactly one square root.

Comment: What the first problem is asking for is "in a cyclic group of even order, prove that the equation $x^2=a$ has either no solution for $x$ or two solutions for $x$". I would also advise picking a few small values of $d$ and investigating those in detail.

Comment: Isnt this something obvious(by taking x and -x)? What values could possibly not have a solution?

Comment: What is "$-x$" in an abstract group? An abstract group only has only one operation, multiplication, and no negative signs.

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic group is generated by some element $g.$ Since the group is order $d,$ our elements are $g, g^2,\dots, g^{d}=e.$

Since $d$ is even, $g^{2k}$ has square roots $g^{k}$ and $g^{k+d/2},$ which you can check are distinct.

The other case is an element of the form $g^{2k+1}.$ For any element of the cyclic group, $g^m,$ its square is $g^{2m},$ which cannot be $g^{2k+1}$. Again this is because $d$ is even: $2m$ is still even modulo $d.$ If $d$ was odd, this wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Sorry, where does $g^{k+d/2}$ come from? Also what about the other values of the generator that arent 2k? It says that the order has to be even but not every element of the group, right?

Comment: Because if you square it, you get $g^{2k+d}=g^{2k}$, therefore it's a square root. All values in the group are covered by those two cases: either an even power of the generator or an odd power - there are no others. In the second paragraph there is a proof the odd ones don't have a square root.

Comment: For odd $d$ (I think the question was edited to include this later), take any $g^k$. If $k$ is even, then $g^{k/2}$ is a square root. If $k$ is odd, $g^{(k+1)/2+(d-1)/2}$ is a square root.

Answer (score 1):

Since $G$ is cyclic it is abelian, so $\{ x^2 | x\in G\} = G^2$ is a (normal) subgroup of G.
This is also valid for when $d$ is odd.

See if you can study the quotient $G/G^2$ and the map $x \mapsto x^2$ for $x\in G$.